# Why is the output for my datediff expression to return a number of days bracketed?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, expression, datediff

I have written the following expression to give me the number of days between a date and today.

```
=IIF(Fields!First_Check_Start_Date.Value = nothing,nothing,datediff("d",Today,Fields!First_Check_Start_Date.Value))
```

The output is correct but is bracketing the number

ie.  (292) instead of 292

Any help as to why this is

Comment: could you please upvote answer as well, it will help me add some points as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using text box to display your result, check what is the type of your text box. Make it as number and look for it's format and set to correct

[image]

Else you could also format like below

```
=IIF(Fields!First_Check_Start_Date.Value = nothing,nothing,Format(datediff("d",Today,Fields!First_Check_Start_Date.Value),"##"))
```

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that whilst viewing in SSRS Report builder the numbers are bracketed (292), however once export to either csv or excel the bracket disappears and is replaced bi a minus -292 which is correct

Thanks